# Why is std::string not trivially destructible?

Tags: c++

I'm a c++ noob and I've been reading about trivial destructibility.

From [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_trivially_destructible/) article on trivial destructibility,

> Trivially destructible types include scalar types, trivially copy
> constructible classes and arrays of such types.
>
> A trivially destructible class is a class (defined with class, struct
> or union) that:
>
> - uses the implicitly defined destructor.
> - the destructor is not virtual.
> - its base class and non-static data members (if any) are    themselves also trivially destructible types.

But apparently std::string is not trivially destructible. Why? Which of the above rules does std::string not satisfy?

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << "std::string is trivially destructible? "
              << std::is_trivially_destructible<std::string>::value << '\n'
```

The above snippet returns the following output:

`std::string is trivially destructible? false`

Comment: How do you believe that `std::string` satisfies any of those 3 conditions mentioned?

Comment: I don't. That is also part of the question. Where is the source code to check how std::string is implemented? How do I evaluate each of the critertion described above?

Comment: any data structures that have dynamic size obviously must have some kind of dynamic allocation, so they can't use the default implicit destructor which doesn't deallocate emmory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `std::string` typically contains a pointer to dynamically allocated character data, so it needs an explicit destructor to deallocate that memory. So, if nothing else, it must either fail this criterion:

> uses the implicitly defined destructor

or have a base class that fails it, in which case it fails this criterion:

> its base class and non-static data members (if any) are themselves also trivially destructible types.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I check the source code for how std::string works?

Comment: @VenkataNarayana The exact location of the source code depends on the implementation you are using. But generally if you are in an IDE, there should be features that redirects you to its definition.

Comment: @VenkataNarayana you don't need the source code to verify this. Just read any `std::string` documentation (like [this one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)), or the C++ standard itself, which defines the interface for `std::string`. Either of those will show you that `std::string` has an explicit destructor defined, thus the "implicitly defined destructor" requirement is not satisfied.